# Fluent NHibernate Cacheing for Linq queries

Tags: caching, fluent-nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I have just discovered that I don't think my nhibernate setup seems to be cacheing properly. I'm running a SQL server profiler and neither the 1st or 2nd level cache appear to be working.

For my queries I'm using:

```
var queryable = NHibernateSession.CurrentFor(NHibernateSession.DefaultFactoryKey).Linq<Accommodation>();
queryable.QueryOptions.SetCachable(true);
```

I've also tried setting this in one of the entity mappings:

```
Cache.Is(c => c.ReadOnly());
```

Is there something else I ought to be doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One person suggests that the 2nd-level cache does not work linq queries if there's a select statement involved. I don't know whether this is a bug or not.

[nhibernate cache problem with linq queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350683/nhibernate-cache-problem-with-linq-queries/3931948)

Another thing worth checking is using explicit transactions:

http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2010/06/16/fluent-nhibernate-and-the-2nd-level-cache/

It's probably more sensible to wait for NH 3.0 and the newer, better linq integration.